# Deadlock on Android's MediaRecorder when using PreviewCallback during video recording

Tags: android, multithreading, camera, mediarecorder

After some issues I finally managed to get video recording working in my App, using the MediaRecorder.

What I want to do now is to process as many preview-frames as possible during recording. I.e. I want to grab a preview frame, process it and ignore any preview frames while processing this one. Once finished processing it I want to go on with the next one coming in.

For this I tried two different approaches:

1. Add two buffers via Camera.addCallbackBuffer() and have a Thread working on one of them while the PreviewCallback is instantly re-adding the currently "unused" buffer whenever a frame is incoming.
2. Use setOneShotPreviewCallback(), process the frame in the callback method and setOneShotPreviewCallback() again.

Processing of one frame takes around 500ms.

With both approaches I get two issues:

1. The preview framerate (on TextureView) decreases a lot
2. Main Issue: In most of the cases I get some kind of dead lock during recording or at the end of the recording.

That's what I do (using the setOneShotPreviewCallback()-approach):

```
MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder();
(prepare Recorder...)

mr.start();
cam.setOneShotPreviewCallback(myCallbackObject);
```

And later, from another Thread I stop recording:

```
mr.stop();
cam.setPreviewCallback(null);
...
```

That's what the callback method does:

```
(do something with the data buffer)
cam.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
```

In most cases my code gets stuck at

```
mr.stop();
```

but sometimes also at

```
cam.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
```

inside the callback.

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Processing one frame takes long enough to justify a) running it in AsyncTask and b) copying the preview frame to a different byte[].

setOneShotPreviewCallback() seems a good choice, but copy the pixels to a preallocated array and return from onPreviewFrame() as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that. Copying the buffer in the onPreviewFrame-method and starting a new thread which processes the copied data. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: Ah, ok! I think I got rid of the "Deadlock" issue. I am calling mr.stop() from the UI thread now and it seems that this won't lock anymore.
But one thing still is a problem: Framerate drop. I can see it on the preview display AND in the resulting video as well (which is even worse!). Why does that happen anyway? Is it too much work for my test device (SGSII)? The only thing I'm doing in the thread which is calling the PreviewCallback is copying the buffer and starting the worker thread.

Comment: Hmm.. Do you see the same slowdown if you don't start the worker thread (no image processing) ?

Comment: When I don't do any processing, there's no slowdown. So I think I'll have to keep CPU load low during recording. Thanks, Alex!

Comment: From your explanation it's not clear if you make sure that there is never more than one image processing thread busy.

Comment: I only call setOneShotPreviewCallback() after processing of a frame is finished. So there should be only one image being processed at a time.

Comment: I don't know what happens there. You could try to call `setOneShotPreviewCallback()` on the UI thread, with some minimal delay - to make sure there is no overlap of multiple worker threads. You could try to set thread priority lower. You could check that the CPU is not getting too hot.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling this method in UI thread now. It all seems to work fine now. And stable :-)